# How about multiple hats?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash

I earned two hats on a site, and I think it would be great if we can wear both at the same time.

Can this please be made possible?

Comment: Don't be greedy!

Comment: The hats visuals are lucrative :P :P

Comment: Why down voting ? Not fare..... :( It's a thought and can be discussed.

Comment: @AYK - FYI - [Voting on Meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: We would also have to be able to define the stacking order (even for two hats). IMHO it would be quite an expensive feature, and the result would be a mess anyway, graphically speaking.

Comment: hmm. Considering the expenses, I can live with a single hat :(. But it all starts from the lucrative visual provided.

Comment: We need [at least ten hat slots](http://trenchescomic.com/comic/post/haberdasher) (and a couple of novelty buckle slots).

Comment: So far, I've been able to wear the [Fez](http://winterba.sh/constantinopolitan "AKA: the Shriner") and the [Bow Tie](http://winterba.sh/the-abby "AKA: the Nation of Islam") together [at the same time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7365809#7365809 "It's magic!").  I'm too lazy to get the other possible combinations, however.

Comment: I mean I even keep my hats forever

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Sorry, I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this idea just because layering that many images on a gravatar isn't really feasible for us -- not without severely sacrificing performance.

That said, there's a fairly easy "cheat" around this -- just screencap your gravatar wearing a hat, make that image your gravatar, and equip a different hat. repeat until you are wearing all the hats! (If you do this, I suggest using the version of profile page!)

Comment: Or just [rotate your hats randomly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159446/eeeek-i-have-too-many-hats-and-cant-decide-which-one-to-wear)...

Comment: I actually figured this out, but more because I was annoyed that the accompanying glasses didn't fit properly with my jauntily cocked hat, no matter how much I fiddled with the controls.  But now I can take my hat with me after January 9th!

Answer (score 2):

If this was real life, you could [definitely wear multiple hats](http://web.archive.org/web/20160111194314/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Many_hats.jpg)!  However, these hats at stackexchange are huge, so only one at a time!

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should!

Comment: It's not fair..