# Eeeek! I have too many hats and can't decide which one to wear!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012, fun

I am loving the new Winter Bash, but I have too many hats! I can't decide which one to wear!

**Eeeek! What do I do? How do I choose which hat to wear!?**

<sub>I should mention to downvoters that [*Josh's Socks* is my sockpuppet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65604/i-am-a-sockpuppet-may-i-exist-if-i-have-a-real-purpose) :-)</sub>

Comment: Needs more "Eeeek!"

Comment: FTFY @JoshCaswell!

Comment: The downvotes have nothing to do with your sockpuppet. The downvotes are because ***by no standards*** is this a constructive question for Meta. The answer should really just be the question.

Comment: @animuson a) welcome to Meta, you should know better. B) I tagged it so it becomes acceptable. You're welcome.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Your tag does not make this acceptable.

Comment: You, sir, are a spoilsport: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/always-friday-in-iceland

Comment: @animuson: This question will be going away when the Winter Bash ends. I specifically posted a bad question **for humor value**. Clearly my intention was to post the userscript. The downvotes don't bother me a bit, in fact I find them quite hysterical :-)

Comment: @animuson: Are you saying that if The Unhandled Exception had posted the answer in the question, you wouldn't instead be complaining that it wasn't a question? I can't see anything wrong with creating a dummy question in order to be able to share a useful/fun script.

Comment: Same goes for almost all "friday in Iceland" posts as they all generally have a limited shelf-life. My most recent AFiI post will be closed on Dec 26th.

Comment: @jcolebrand: You'd also notice over half those questions are... closed.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException, that's reassuring, I was already seeing the `Are sockpuppets allowed on meta?` questions arriving in droves.

Comment: @Josh: No, I would've upvoted it - it's a cool little script. Many people post things like that on Meta, I've even posted a user-script on the Gaming Meta before. But posting a silly question to post an answer to is just bad form.

Comment: @animuson what part of "limited shelf life" .. ya know what? Just leave it alone for two more weeks, then cry about it. Promise.

Comment: @animuson then downvote the question, and upvote the answer. You seem to be misunderstanding that *bad form was my intention with the question!* It's playing off all the bad MSO questions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi he should be the only popular sockpuppet, except of course for MarcGravell and TimStone being RebeccaChern's sockpuppets, who is of course a sock for GraceNote, but I digress ...

Comment: Also, **I did not vote on my sockpuppet's answer (other than to accept it)** and he did not vote on my question. He really does exist so I can test things like this (and so I can annoy rchern) :-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException, seems like you're getting away with it this time again. Beware though: you may be unhandled *now*, but *someday, someone* will catch you.

Comment: first stack exchange wolrd problems.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Do you have too many hats? Can't decide which one to wear? Want to make sure you're always showing off how many hats you have but don't have time to click through them all? Do you suffer from crippling indecision where even life's smallest choices bring you to your knees?

#### Fear not!

### The answer you seek is here!

## Josh's Socks' Ultra Hat Selector 5000™

**(patent pending)**

### Now with support for changing Community's hat (mods only)

With **Josh's Socks' Ultra Hat Selector 5000™** you'll never need to worry about which hat to wear again! Simply [Install this userscript](http://josh.gitlin.name/userscripts/JoshsSocksHatSelector-1.1.user.js) and visit your user profile page. There you'll find a new "Randomly change my hat" feature!

[image: Randomly change my hat]

1. First, **Open your list of hats** by clicking the **hats** link to load the hats into your browser. Then you can close the list.
2. Then, check the "Randomly change my hat" checkbox.
3. Enter a duration in `H:MM:SS` format. For example, enter `1:30:00` to change your hat every hour and a half.
4. The countdown will begin and your hat will be changed and the countdown reset automatically. **Leave this tab open**, if you close the tab, you close the Josh's Socks' Ultra Hat Selector 5000™. Your hat will not change on this tab but will change elsewhere on the site!

**NOTES:**

- **Do not close the tab which is running the countdown**. This tab must remain open for the script to work.
- **The tab with the countdown will not update**. A refresh would be needed (or more time in teh code) to refresh the hat, and a refresh would stop the countdown
- **If you get more hats, you'll need to refresh the tab** and restart the countdown. The hats are cached when you open the hat selector, so only those hats will be randomized. If you earn new hats, refresh and start the script again.
- **Hats are cached on every user's browser** so use a reasonable countdown like 5 or 10 minutes *at least*. Changing your hat every 15 seconds won't take effect to anyone but you.

## Happy Winter Hat Dash Bash!

Comment: This is what happens when I leave you guys alone to go to the store... *shakes head*

Comment: Didn't check if it's really working, but +1 just for the description and marketing! :D

Comment: [I'm using it now](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/13/josh-gitlin), it's working great!

Comment: Wow - did you really do that in 1 minute?

Comment: @Rory: it's a sockpuppet, so one and same user ;) See also [user profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151695/joshs-socks).

Comment: d'oh - I am a gullible fool

Comment: Note the gravatar @RoryAlsop :-)

Comment: Yes, we all know why you're "busy" at work now.  Those `Gitlin Site-in-a-box 5000 Mark V`s aren't going to sell themselves.