# Hats + StackExchange API

Tags: feature-request, api, winter-bash-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we programmatically retrieve hat counts via an API call?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159801/can-we-programmatically-retrieve-hat-counts-via-an-api-call)

I realize they're only around until January 4th, but is there any chance of getting hat data available in the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This is gonna be one hell of a long Friday... -.-

Comment: Why? It's not like I'm asking for [multiple hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats). Hat data in the API is a very feasible thing; they already have apps for [tracking badge progress](http://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges). Why not hats?

Comment: Badges are permanent, hats are temporary bonus. That's the difference.

Comment: This really isn't the worst request in the world, the whole point to the API is to encourage developers to create great apps in the Stack Exchange ecosystem.  It's fine to say "there are more immediate concerns that need to be addressed with the API" but the general response here is toeing the line on saying "this is stupid", which is never an appropriate response anywhere on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Agreed @JollyOldSaintNicholas.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas If I thought the request was stupid, I'd vote to close and then vote to delete when it was closed, I don't waste time answering questions if I think they are stupid.

Answer (score 11):

### No.

Hats are only going to last until January 4, there'd be absolutely no point in asking the developers to update the API for something that's supposed to be silly, fun and *ephemeral*. There are [5000+ feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5Bfeature-request%5D%20-%5Bstatus-declined%5D%20-%5Bstatus-completed%5D%20-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D%20-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D%20-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D%20closed:0) and [2,037 bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D%20-%5Bstatus-declined%5D%20-%5Bstatus-completed%5D%20-%5Bstatus-bydesign%5D%20-%5Bstatus-deferred%5D%20-%5Bstatus-norepro%5D%20-%5Bstatus-planned%5D%20closed:0&submit=search) that deserve more attention than this.

Comment: No sense in being incomplete. I could see many, many uses for the hat data, even in the short period they're around.

Comment: Let's hear it for silliness. Hup! Hup! Hurray!

Comment: And yet, the [first thing that we have a write API for is the most ephemeral of things, comments](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/stack-exchange-api-v2-1/).

Comment: Ah, but comments weren't initially supposed to be ephemeral, you can't blame the devs, who could predict you'd get a diamond? Or that I would? ;P On a more serious note _most_ comments survive for a lot longer than hats will...

Answer (score 0):

Somebody write a web-stripping PHP script.