# Can we programmatically retrieve hat counts via an API call?

Tags: support, status-declined, api, winter-bash-2012

I'd like to be able to get access to the leader board data on winterba.sh, as well as individual hat counts for specific users on different sites. There is, however, no mention of an API on winterba.sh.

Given that one exists for everything else on all of the sites, is one available there? If not, would it be possible to add one just to retrieve this data with a GET request?

Answer (score 4):

We won't be offering an API for something as ephemeral as hats.

Too much work for something that's just supposed to be a fun one-off.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the importance of hats sir

Comment: clearly we should hire a full time hat dev

Comment: @Jin agreed. HAT DEVS INITIATE!