# Can we have a Winterbash overall leaderboard?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2012

Can we see a hat leaderboard for all SE users alongside the leaderboards of the sites?

Comment: Well I guess if you really want to you could formulate a query here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk are the hats even in there?

Comment: Thats what i'm looking for right now. I've seen many posts stating that hats are treated as badges so i'm looking into it. It should be somewhere in here : http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/

Comment: Pretty sure the data is being stored in an entirely different set of tables, on account of the API is completely different for the hats.

Comment: The hats won't be in the API: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159535/hats-stackexchange-api and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159801/can-we-programmatically-retrieve-hat-counts-via-an-api-call

Comment: @jcolebrand your edit made no sense...

Comment: What are you talking about? You want to see a hat leaderboard per-site, that's what you're asking for. You don't want just ANY leaderboard, you want a hat leaderboard.

Comment: @jcolebrand the hat leaderboard per site already exists lol. I want a hat leaderboard for the **whole** SE.

Comment: Then you SERIOUSLY need to reword your question, because it doesn't convey that. In addition, why would they do that? What you want then is a winterbash leaderboard.

Comment: @jcolebrand ahhh that title makes more sense! ^_^ I was just editing as well to that affect. thanks. Sorry that the title was a lil confusing X_x

Comment: Not just the title but the body too. Now I see what you're after.

Comment: What exactly would you want this to show? Users with the highest *total* number of hats across the network (all hats earned added together)? Users sorted by highest number of hats earned on a single site? I'm sort of confused what you're envisioning and what purpose it would serve. (I'm not involved in the Winter Bash execution, but I'd hazard a guess that this won't be implemented. Between people being on vacation over the holidays, it's a time-urgent request, and there isn't a clear purpose for it, doesn't seem to make sense to put the work in to make it happen.)

Comment: @Laura well then it could be useful for next year :-)

Answer (score 4):

The feature requests that are coming in for Winter Bash, IMHO, should be status-declined. This is an event that's designed to be fun, and it's an event that is really only going to last for another 12 days, then it will be over.

I've encountered some bugs, but I've not reported them because there isn't really a point in fixing something that will be gone shortly after the New Year. In addition, as Laura mentions, most of the team is on vacation and won't be available.

Aside from that, there's really no guarantee that this same event would be held next season either, which makes this, and any other Winter Bash request, an extremely low priority.

There are many other feature-requests yet to be implemented that will have a positive effect on the network year-round, and we should focus on those instead. For instance, we could focus on [ways to make it clear how to improve a question to reopen it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120372/155826), which would be helpful for many users who don't frequent meta.

Answer (score 3):

This leaderboard is added with Winterbash 2013! You can see this here: [The Stack Exchange Network - Network-wide leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network)

In the leaderboard only unique hats are counted.