# All I want is a well-fitted hat!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, winter-bash-2013, winter-bash, winter-bash-2014

I just got a new hat! :D *screaming with joy* Looking at so many users looking all exquisite with their stunningly 'fitted' hats, I'm wondering if there's an option to resize or rotate a hat?

PS: Happy Winter Bash everyone! :)

Comment: You can move the hat, but not resize or rotate it

Comment: You can resize your gravatar instead.

Comment: "Looking at so many users looking all exquisite with their stunningly 'fitted' hats..." They're cheating, they took a new picture of themselves and positioned the hat accordingly.

Comment: This is an iterative process. We could not even move the hats last year. Maybe next year we will be able to resize them, then rotate them the year after, then change their colors or something circa 2020.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, users will design the hats in 2050 ;)

Comment: @Mr.PeanutMonopolyMcManish Oh.. That's a great tip! :)

Comment: @ankitaalung - Or you can simply create a Photoshopped image of yours along with the hat and upload that as your display image :)

Comment: @R.J, then she should hate the flags to view it.

Comment: @R.J with a photo-shopped image, I can boast off with the fanciest of headgears! But we don't wanna do that, do we? :)

Comment: @ankitaalung - Yeah that there. Also, the secret to get the secret hats wouldn't be revealed. ;) Love the winter bash on SE :)

Comment: @Azik - Or may be [multiple hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159307/187824) by 2060?

Comment: @ankitaalung nice hat by the way :D

Comment: @dholakiyaankit u think so? :D

Comment: ya ha ha ha i don't have this one @ankitaalung :(

Comment: Aww! All I wanted was a DownDo hat, but you guys won't let me have one... `;( ;( ;(`

Comment: Awww! @Qantas94Heavy dont worry! You'll get one soon.. ;P

Comment: @ankitaalung - Be diplomatic: if the hat does not adapt to you, adapt yourself to the hat. Change the avatar photo with one in which you raise your hands to the sky.... then using that yellow triangle hat you can at least pretend to be Link (or Zelda, but that would require switching from the green dress to a more elaborate one).

Answer (score 27):

Sorry, but I have to decline this. The main problem with this is that I want to keep the hat image files used on the major pages – in other words, the question pages – small, because every visitor has to load them. But in order to make scaled or rotated hats (where sub-pixels start to matter) not look horrible, the base image size would have to be much bigger.

**Update**, one year later: For Winter Bash 2014, we switched to using SVG images, and you can now rotate and scale your hats.

Comment: "the base image size would have to be much bigger." SVG?

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Sure, that's a thing we can look at next year, but this year we're stuck with bitmaps.

Comment: You're using [an image sprite](http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash2013/img/sprite-32.png). Users only have to load it once. Your servers only have to serve it once per user.

Comment: Also, I notice that the hats are the last thing to load on a page, so I would bet you have something going where it is loaded last so the page does not appear to lag and loads all the important content first.

Comment: @fredsbend I'm talking about the vast majority of people who come in from Google through a question link and only ever see one page. For these people "once" is equivalent to "always". And this is not about "our servers" (the images are on a CDN anyway).

Comment: I guess I don't understand the problem. That one image is only 57KB. A doubling in size is not that significant. Also, I'm sure you could make it so that it only shows to logged in users (but maybe the promotion is meant to attract new users, though it seems to be designed to keep regular users throughout the holidays). I understand not doing it *this year* because of time. For future years, it doesn't seem like that big of a deal.

Comment: @balpha you can create several "versions" of the same hat, for some of the hats. Not custom resizing or rotating but rather several "tailored" options. Is this feasible request for next year? :)

Comment: On the update: maybe I need a dunce cap, but what's the UI for doing the rotation and scaling? Can only figure out how to move it...

Comment: Oh! I _do_ deserve the dunce cap. "Show controls" button!

Comment: Perhaps also update the tag on the question to `[status-complete]`?

Comment: @mattdm "After choosing a hat on your hat rack and before clicking “Wear hat,” you can move your hat around on your avatar with your mouse (or, on a touch screen, your finger). For advanced adjustments or if you don't want the hat to disappear behind your finger while moving it, check the “show controls” box. This will display two handles that you can drag around, one for moving the hat and one for resizing and rotating it." (from the [FAQ](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/faq)). It also showed the UI, I believe, in the blog post.

Comment: @TravisJ Fair enough, it's a WB 2013 question, but I guess it doesn't matter much.

Comment: It's a WB 2014 question now. :-)

Answer (score 11):

As noted by [@balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212070/178816), this is now live.

Here is how you use it:

[image]

- Red: When you select the check mark for "show controls" the brown and blue controls are shown.
- Brown: This control is a click and drag, and allows for the line between the hat and the control to dictate size (by distance) and rotation (by angle).
- Blue: This control is a click and drag, and allows the hat placement to be moved much like a window would be moved. If the hat is moved towards the edge of the avatar zone, the hat shrinks automatically. You may also move the hat by dragging directly on it.

Comment: The blue thing isn't strictly necessary; you can move the hat without "show controls" just by dragging the hat itself. I just added the blue drag handle for two reasons: a) It makes it more obvious that you *can* move it, and b) on touch screens, where your mouse cursor is your finger, it's nice that you can move your hat while it's not hidden under your finger, so you can see how it fits your avatar.

Answer (score 3):

You actually *don't* need the controls to make the hat smaller. Just drag it out of your profile picture, like this:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

We do not have any option to resize or rotate the hat. We have only to move the hat which can be done while selecting the hat. May be this should be a feature request for the next Winterbash.

Comment: It would be awesome...we could wear the Passed Judgement as beard!

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Oh how great is a human mind! :D cheers

Comment: Yup, that's a valid request for next year. And to think previous year we couldn't even change the hat position... how did we survive?! ;-)

Comment: We still survived [very well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161206/187824) @Sha :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, All I can say is, we can close this question as status declined and reopen next year.

Comment: @Azik - May be [status-planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned)

Comment: @hims056 show off! As for tag... [meta-tag:status-next-year] sounds just right. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's the the important coding and on-site considerations, such as how big or small can it go, does it fit ok at smallest and largest across all possible placements, etc, etc.

But more than that, aren't the hats just a bit of fun?
You have your avatar, then for a few weeks in winter Stack provide some hats to slap on your avatar for a good old simplistic bit of fun.
Resize, change colours, rotate, all unnecessary and in fact I think would take some of the fun element away from them.
If the hat fit perfectly it would just look like any old real avatar image, whereas I like seeing them hap-hazard and *slapped on* looking too high or low or too wide etc. Makes them look like a fun-like stick-on bit of a laugh.

Each to their own of course, but if you feel that strongly about it, use a graphic editor and resize it yourself directly onto your avatar image and re-upload.