# Wear a hat multiple times?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

I've searched all over meta and found [this feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats) for wearing multiple hats that was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). But today I saw [9 Shogs a-Shogging ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/9-shogs-a-shogging) profile.

[image]

Is there really a way to wear two hats or is this something out the ordinary?

Comment: Kinda looks cool. Maybe a mod privilege?!

Comment: Thought experiment. Take your gravater. Take the hat sprite (or image). Create a **new** gravatar, resizing and moving said hat till it fits nicely. Use new gravatar with cropped hat. Add hat.

Comment: @Oded Yeah. Now its time for me to wear my unicorn hat 3 times :D

Comment: *Chuckles at Shog's Christmas nickname.*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Make a screenshot of you wearing a hat.
2. Reduce the size with an image editor.
3. Upload your new profile picture.
4. Add a hat.

Comment: Damn!!!. Why didn't I think of this???

Comment: @Chenmunka If the hat ends up anywhere near their face we will know there is something awry!